# How avoid recurrent code in block with ruby?

Tags: ruby, linux

I try to convert a bash script in a ruby script just for playing.I have to check one word and this word will be used to the other function.The bash script look like:

```
f_checkword(){  # Ask for user name
  unset word
  while [ -z "${word}" ]; do read -p "Enter your name ame: " word; done
  echo -e "\e[1;34m[*]\e[0m OK"
}


f_dosomethingwiththeword(){  # Function checking the name
  f_checkword  # Function asking the name of the user
  if grep -q "${Word}" "word.txt" ; then 
    echo -e "\t\e[1;32m [+] Name is OK"
  else 
    echo -e "Enter your name please"
  fi
}
```

I call the `f_checkword` function and then it is OK we follow the `f_dosomethingwiththeword()` function. In ruby I can't do this because the value of the word is doesn't save.

```
class Word
  def self.dosomeWord
    checkWord()
    puts "Name is:"
  end


  def self.dosomethingwiththeWord
    checkWord()
    puts "Name is:"
    puts "#{word}"
  end


  def self.checkWord
    puts "[*]Checking your entries..."
    File.open("word.txt").readlines.each do |word|
     puts word
     word = word.chomp
     if word.chomp.start_with?('bob', 'july', 'Smith')
       puts "[+]Name is OK"
     else
       puts "[-]ERROR: wrong name"
     end
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please properly indent your code, it's very hard to read.

Comment: Also I'm not sure what is the question here.

Comment: Your bash script is incomplete and doesn't reflect your explanation _"call the check word method and then [...] dosomethingmethod"_. Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok i edited the post sorry.

Comment: The Bash script stores the input value in the environment variable `word`; environment variables are global. The Ruby code stores the input value in the local variable `word`. Make it use a global variable or, better, a property of the class.

Comment: How i can use it with a global variable ? do you have a link or a example for that ? i want to avoid too much same code in the block, because the name will be check in other funtion too.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.I just use 'load' checkword.rb instead of call by the function name.Checkword is define as global.